# Post request to Express api (Node js) from react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, body-parser

I am trying to post data from react front-end to express that is node API.

Below is the code from react (front-end) to post data:

```
generateOTPForLogin(phone_number){ 
    console.log('transfer data');
    fetch(
        API_URL+'/generateOTP', {  
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            phone_number: phone_number
        })
    });
}
```

Below is the code where I am getting the request in user controller :

```
        exports.generateOTP = (req,res) => {
            console.log('generating otp...',req.body);  
// generating otp... { '{"phone_number":"+9999999"}': '' } 
        }
    }
```

Here you can check how I am receiving the data, the whole JSON is in the request body key and value in empty.

> How can I get the response as  { "phone_number":"+9999999"} ?

Below you can get the app settings:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import favicon from 'serve-favicon';
import logger from 'morgan'; 
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'; 

module.exports= function (app){
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.engine('view engine', require('jade').renderFile);
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
};
```

Please help  me to know what is the issue here. I have tried to post data using POSTMAN , with this below settings it is working fine and I am getting proper data:

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/generateOTP",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  },
  "data": {
    "phone_number": "+999999999"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**I have found a solution , but partially:**

```
generateOTPForLogin(phone_number){
        var details = {
            phone_number: "+91"+phone_number
        };

        var formBody = [];
        for (var property in details) {
            var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
            var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
            formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue); 
        }

        formBody = formBody.join("&");

        fetch( API_URL+'/generateOTP', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: formBody
        }).then(function(responseOTP){
            console.log("resp:",responseOTP);
            alert(responseOTP);
        }).catch(function(errorOTP){
            console.log("error:",errorOTP); //TypeError: Failed to fetch
            alert(errorOTP);
        });
    }
```

I am able to post the data and getting two errors:

1. In chrome browser I am getting this issue:  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3006' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Front end running in : localhost:3006

Backend running in : localhost:3000

2. In the then and catch part while receiving the response in react, I am unable to get it in then promise, its going for catch which prints: TypeError: Failed to fetch.

How can I solve the above issues ?

Comment: You didn't describe the problem or ask a question. What doesn't work? What is expected?

Comment: Please check the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution:

```
generateOTPForLogin(phone_number){
    console.log('transfer data');

    var details = {
        phone_number: "+91"+phone_number
    };

    var formBody = [];
    for (var property in details) {
        var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
        var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
        formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue); 
    }

    formBody = formBody.join("&");

    fetch( API_URL+'/generateOTP', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: formBody
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJSON) => {
        console.log(responseJSON);
    })
    .catch((errResp) => {
        console.log(errResp)
    });
}
```

In node side :

```
//commented using default cors
// app.use(cors());

// Provided origin of front end in whitelist list
    var whitelist = ['http://localhost:3006']
    var corsOptions = {
      origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
          callback(null, true)
        } else {
          callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
      }
    }

    app.use('/', cors(corsOptions), index_route);
```